# Android Python Missing Basic Modules

Tags: android, python

I am new to Android. I'm running an ASUS Eee Pad Transformer TF101 with ICS. I installed the Terminal IDE app and ran `python`. Ostensibly, I am running 2.6.2. However, when I run

```
>>> import random
```

it gives me an `ImportError`.

What gives? Do I have to root my device to use basic 2.6 modules?

Comment: As far as I know Terminal IDE does not support Python. Where have you read that? On the main page on Google Play it does not speak about Python.

Comment: @rubik:  in order to get an ImportError, it would seem python would need to be running.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: That's a good point, and that's what I first thought. But Python is not the only to raise `ImportError`'s. The OP should post the whole traceback to get useful information. Anyway, in Terminal IDE Google Play entry Python is not listed. Can you provide some useful links? I would be interested too.

Comment: @rubik: Terminal IDE launches the python interpreter and runs python programs. It just doesn't import certain standard modules. For example, it *will* import `math` but not `random`.

Comment: If Terminal IDE doesn't have full support for Python 2.6, does someone know a terminal that does? It seems bizarre to me that they would provide a "half-linux" implementation. I would think it is all or nothing.

Comment: This sounds to me as if the standard library is not included but only the interpreter. Can you try if other modules are available (especially `sys`)? And check the paths in `sys.path` and the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Hmm. `sys` imports correctly. It has paths to `python26.zip`, `python2.6`, and `lib-dynload`. I thought Android was Linux-based and that these programs were giving me direct access to the kernel shell. I didn't know that different terminal apps had different functionality. Maybe I'll try Better Terminal Emulator Pro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, none of the terminal emulators on the Play Store have access to the standard libraries. I finally found a system that does called SL4A. I installed it and am following the User Guide here:

http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/UserGuide

I've installed the Python interpreter and successfully imported `random`.

Answer (score 3):

Having the same question, I stumbled across [this link](http://tinyrobot.co.uk/blog/python-in-terminal-ide-for-android/) which provides a simple 'python' script...but am not too sure how useful such a thing is.

> Please note the below takes into account just using python with
>   Terminal IDE, and I’ve not linked anything to /system/bin because not
>   everyone who has Terminal IDE installed will want to have root, so our
>   python script is kept in Terminal IDE’s home, which in turn is added
>   to the path in .bashrc.

Create below file as ~/python:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
BASE=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python
export PYTHONPATH=${PYTHONPATH}:${BASE}/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
export PYTHONHOME=${BASE}
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${BASE}/lib
${BASE}/bin/python "$@"
```

Then made it executable and added ~/ to my $PATH in ~/.bashrc:

```
terminal++@127.0.0.1:~$ chmod +x ~/python
terminal++@127.0.0.1:~$ echo export PATH=$PATH:~/ >> ~/.bashrc
```

And now when you restart Terminal IDE, you should be able to type ‘python’ to get the interactive python interpreter!

Comment: I'd like to plug _[my solution](http://blog.lankycyril.com/post/39473303019)_ that builds on the one you posted here, allowing to run .py files with "#!/usr/bin/python" in the header etc.

Answer (score 0):

Following the blog post at [lankycyril.com](http://blog.lankycyril.com/post/39473303019), I ended up with the same problem where Python actually runs, but can't find any of the basic modules that come with it. The blog post also doesn't seem to address the issue at hand.

After playing around a little, all you really need to do when defining PYTHONPATH is add the path to the modules themselves as well, so modify this (from the blog):

```
export PYTHONHOME=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python
export PYTHONPATH=~/py:${PYTHONHOME}/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PYTHONHOME}/lib
```

to this (note second line):

```
export PYTHONHOME=/data/data/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/files/python
export PYTHONPATH=~/py:${PYTHONHOME}/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload:${HOME}/sdcard/com.googlecode.pythonforandroid/extras/python
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${PYTHONHOME}/lib
```

All that was missing from the PYTHONPATH was the path to the modules themselves, so Python had no idea where to load them from. Adding the path to those modules solved the problem for me.

Hope this helps.